# Android O - Background service limitation not working as expected

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

I was just testing my existing android application against Android O background limitations.

In testing, I found a strange behavior. So basically in my application, I am using background service and I am starting it in very first activity.

So now the issue is once the activity and background service gets started, I am closing my activity using the back button. So as per the service concepts, it keeps running in the background.

After approx 1 min `onDestroy()` method gets called of background service but still the service keeps running. Ideally as per the documentation it should be get killed.

So, I don't know whether it is an issue or what.

For reference, I have created a sample code which reflects the same scenario which is as below:

**Steps**

- Start application
- Click on Start background service button.
- Close application using the back button.

**HomeActivity.java**

```
package com.icpl.otest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

import com.icpl.otest.service.MyService;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    public void onStartServiceClick(View view) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
package com.icpl.otest.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    private Handler mHandler;

    public MyService() {
        Log.i(TAG, "MyService constructor called.");
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand with intent:- " + intent);
        startShowingVisibility();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void startShowingVisibility() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "I am alive");
                startShowingVisibility();
            }
        }, 3000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After approx 1 min onDestroy() method gets called of background service but still the service keeps running

No, it does not. The *work* that your service may have started may keep going (in your case, your infinite `Handler` "loop"). However, your process may be terminated at any moment.

Comment: I have cleared the `mHandler` object in `onDestroy` method and it worked. Now, whenever system stops my service due to background limitations, service handles it gracefully. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MohitCharadva i don't understand the answer given by commonsware. So can you please explain?I want to know that can i run a service in the background in android O? You told that you close the application by pressing back button, that means you minimize the activity, am i right?