# Android O - My service keeps running in the background for 20+ minutes already. Isn't it supposed to be stopped?

Tags: android

So, I read the scary documentation of Android O and it says that once the app is in background, services will die, and I should refactor my code to use either Foreground services or job scheduler.

In my app I am uploading photos to server, and if the server returns 500 error or there's no network connection, I have a service that retries every 5 minutes, all the time, regardless of whether the app is in foreground or not. It uses a `Timer` to do so

`timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {`

So I upgraded my phone to Android O and ran my app, put it in background, opened 10 more apps and started watching Logcat.

And now, 25 minutes later, my service keeps running the scheduled `TimerTask` every 5 minutes.

Why is it still alive, and does it make sense for me to refactor my app if that's the case?

There's a similar question here:
[Android O - Background service limitation not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611706/android-o-background-service-limitation-not-working-as-expected)

but the answer is too cryptic, especially the part that says " your process may be terminated at any moment." - this has always been the case for android. Is it more probable to a different degree this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it still alive

Perhaps your service itself is not alive, but your service leaks its `Timer`, and your process is still alive. Since your question has no significant code, we can only guess.

> does it make sense for me to refactor my app if that's the case?

Yes.

> Is it more probable to a different degree this time?

Yes. The process importance is a key metric for determining which processes get terminated (and when) by the "OOM killer" that is responsible for terminating Android SDK processes to free up system RAM. Your process will only have elevated importance (compared to an ordinary cached process) when your service is running. Android 8.0 stops the service, but it does not immediately terminate the process, allowing the ordinary OOM killer logic to proceed normally. From the standpoint of your process lifetime, it is still non-deterministic, as it always has been, but the likelihood of a short lifetime is much greater.

Besides, your current implementation isn't great from the user's standpoint. **Only have a service running when it is actively delivering value to the user**, as you are tying up system RAM that the user might prefer be used for other things. Watching the clock tick is not actively delivering value to the user.

Use `JobScheduler` (if your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher) or a compatibility wrapper around it, like Evernote's `android-job` (if your `minSdkVersion` is below 21). Then, you can have the same basic functionality as before, but allow for better memory management. And, as a side benefit, you address this Android 8.0 issue.

Comment: thank you. yeah its 21+ for me so JobScheduler will work just fine. And yeah, I suppose I am leaking the TimerTask - it is started and never touched again until onDestroy where I cancel it. But onDestroy hasn't been called for  50+ minutes now.

Comment: btw is the entire app in the RAM if the service/process is still running because of a leaker TimerTask, or is it only this component that is loaded in memory

Comment: @K.R.: "it is started and never touched again until onDestroy where I cancel it" -- OK, you're not leaking it then. "But onDestroy hasn't been called for 50+ minutes now" -- what is your `targetSdkVersion`? The ~1 minute service lifetime is for `targetSdkVersion` of 26+, or if the user manually asks Android to enable background optimizations for it (only for apps that show up on the "battery blame" list). "is the entire app in the RAM if the service/process is still running" -- by default, yes.

Comment: targetSdk is 26 in my case :)

Comment: last question: can I use GCM Network Manager instead of Job Scheduler? Job Scheduler minimum for periodic tasks is 15 minutes, but I need 1 or 5 minutes.